For mobile apps, usability of search textboxes with different colors?
This may sound like a stupid question, but here goes.
Is there some type of usability purpose to having a white search textbox with a border as opposed to a border-less textbox with a "disabled" color fill?
For example, Amazon and zillow have a regular white search textbox with a border, while home depot and glassdoor have a disabled fill.
From a usability perspective, is there a difference?

Could you add a screenshot of both examples please?

First, let's acknowledge that both designs are trying to achieve the same goal: making the search function easily discoverable and inviting to use. However, they're employing different visual cues to communicate this to users.
The primary insight here is that the choice between a bordered white textbox and a borderless, filled textbox can indeed impact usability, but the effects are nuanced and context-dependent. Let's break this down:
Affordance and Recognition: The bordered white textbox (Amazon, Zillow) relies on a more traditional form input pattern. It's a design that's been around since the early days of web forms, which means it has the advantage of familiarity. Users instantly recognize it as a place to input text.
The filled, borderless design (Home Depot, Glassdoor) is a more modern approach. It stands out visually but might not be as immediately recognizable to all users as an input field.
Visual Hierarchy and Attention: The filled design tends to draw more attention, especially on predominantly white backgrounds. This can be beneficial for search-centric interfaces where you want the search function to be front and center.
The white, bordered design is more subtle. It integrates well with other page elements but might not stand out as much.
Perceived Interactivity: Interestingly, the "disabled" color fill might actually communicate that the field is interactive and waiting for input. It's similar to how a button might have a hover state, inviting interaction.
The white, bordered field relies more on learned behavior and might not feel as "alive" until the user interacts with it.
Consistency with Design Systems: The choice often aligns with the overall design system of the website. Amazon's utilitarian, information-dense design fits well with the classic bordered input. Home Depot's more modern, spacious design allows for the filled search bar to shine.
